# Regex match after first letter (including the letter) in UUID string

Tags: regex, scala, uuid

I have a UUID generated string which I have generated and replaced the "-" with nothing, So What I would like to achieve is to traverse the string and get the first letter and the next 11 chars after that. How would the regex look like?

Comment: Something like `[A-Za-z].{11}` should work.

Comment: Why do you want to do it with regex? you can do str.head and str.tail

Comment: @RamanMishra But would that start the substring at the _first letter_?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i don't think it will start the subString? we can use head and tail

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it seems like author wants to split string at 1st char

Comment: @RamanMishra Oh...I interpreted it to mean the first _letter_ (and not _number_).  Now that I think about it, your interpretation seems to make more sense.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen actually he can use splitAt he knows the index it will return (String, String).

Comment: You know, if you'd bothered to post a few example inputs with expected outputs then there wouldn't be so many wild guesses at what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

you can use following methods:

```
val str ="2e00136a-f639-4a0a-bdfd-c4f972cacc79"
println(str.filter(_.isLetter).take(11))
```

**output:**

```
//eafaabdfdcf
```

if you want to do it only with regex you can do like this.

```
println(str.replaceAll("(\\W+|\\d)", "").take(11))
```

**output:**

```
//eafaabdfdcf
```

Comment: But What I want to achieve is the first letter and the rest 11 chars, There are no letters in that string.

Comment: @AmirSarvestani it's string it could be anything let me it has exactly 12 char or it could be more than 12 char?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
scala> val uuidString = UUID.randomUUID().toString   //43813b1b-1a10-4d1d-bbe5-6a18394797c7
uuidString.filter(_.isLetter).take(11)

scala> res3: String = bbaddbbeac
```

Comment: Thanks @Puneeth but this gives me only 8 characters. As soon as I see the first letter I would like to capture it and get the next 11 chars. So in that instance it would be e95a848c5304

Comment: Modified the answer.

Comment: Still won't work. You never know how many letters you have in a UUID!

Comment: If available you get expected (1 + 11)chars.